# Application error after upgrading from .net3.5 to .net 4.8 framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.8

I am working on upgrading legacy .net application. It was written in .net 2.0 , I have upgraded the framework to 3.5. Deployed into IIS with runtime version v2.0. It worked fine.

And now I have upgraded it to v4.8, it is working fine from my location machine, when I execute the application. So I published it , copied the published folder to dev server , made necessary changes in:
IIS  - (the application needs to be on Windows authentication - so enabled)
- Application pool ( two pools available , 1. target on runtime v2.0
2. target on runtime v4.0)
Whichever pool I use, application is not running. It prompts to authenticate, even though
I enter correct credentials, it still prompts me to enter credentials. When I cancel I see the below message.

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I referred these with no help to my problem.
[ASP.NET MVC application problems after upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798800/asp-net-mvc-application-problems-after-upgrade)
[Framework upgrade from .net 3.5 to .net 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309919/framework-upgrade-from-net-3-5-to-net-4-8)
[Unable to access web application after upgrading from .Net Framework 4.6 to .Net Framework 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326343/unable-to-access-web-application-after-upgrading-from-net-framework-4-6-to-net)

Thank you for help in advance.